# How to reset VS Code configuration to code in Python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

How to reset VS Code configuration to code in Python?
It was working properly. But then I was practising C coding in VS Code. Now I can not run any Python program from VS Code with the Run button at top right, as I was able to, before configuring it to make it fit for C coding.

I cleared the JSON block but it didn't help.

Comment: You're more or less expected to use a different directory for each project.  That directory has the JSON configuration for the language you're using.

Comment: "I emptied the JSON block" - What exact JSON do you mean? VSCode's configuration is splitted across several JSON files, and run configurations are located in `.vscode/launch.json` by default. In this file you can set up several launch configurations and switch between them. See also: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Comment: Never use the Top-Right Run button. Use launch configs.

Comment: See if this link helps your issue: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_configure-and-run-the-debugger

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) has been installed.

Then you can click **Run Python File** to run the script.

[image]